# Another edit spammer

Tags: discussion, status-completed, spam, account-suspension

Just noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008455/bob-jem?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) user. Been spamming YouTube links randomly into a particular question with the message "FOREVER BABY". Just joined today. Looks like this account should be suspended for spamming with absolutely no contributions.

Comment: And two people actually approved one of those edits...

Comment: @Mysticial: Really? Wow. Like really, WOW.

Comment: @Mysticial: They should be banned from reviewing suggested edits FOREVER BABY.

Comment: @animuson: Agreed.

Comment: @NullUserException: Is this worthy of account suspension?

Comment: @Linuxios Waste of time. I just destroyed the account.

Comment: The user doesn't even have any posts to flag and get a moderators attention, though I'm sure this post will suffice.

Comment: I'd totally approve it if it were [Hello!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDZcqBgCS74), but this is just ridiculous. (I kid! I kid! Please don't go all Lionel on the site)

Comment: @TimPost: :). +1.

Comment: **To close voters**: the issue was *fixed*, not *no longer reproducible*. That close reason is intended for *ephemeral* issues that resolve themselves after a short while, not for actual bugs that are later marked completed. The [tag:status-completed] tag is enough.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog The actual reason I flagged this was not because it was no longer reproducible, but because it was specific to one site.

Comment: A migration to Meta.SO would probably be in order

Comment: @Linuxios This question is too old to be migrated.

Comment: Good point @pppery

Comment: Voted to leave closed only because it is no longer relevant to Meta SE.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a better solution.

[image: screenshot]

And for the users approving those edits there's an even better solution:

[image: super sekret mod tools]

Comment: Oh golden hammer of thor.  How I wish I could wield thee.

Comment: It needs to be re-titled to BURNiNATE!

Comment: +1.  How about the +1,000,000 for me? ;).

Comment: (Not a fan of the cancer one :(

Comment: @DaveNewton: agreed

Comment: how does "taunt user" work?

Comment: @prusswan Suspends the user, and sends a mod message with one of the following: "Quit hitting yourself!  Quit hitting yourself!", "I know you are, but what am I?", or "Your mom goes to college."

Comment: I thought the options in the second screen shot did not exist. I'll have to find links. I'm thinking you just posted something you weren't supposed to.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber The screen shot doesn't show even more seekrit options, like instantly sending users Chinese finger traps.